# Google maps markers appears multiple times on wide map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm having this problem where the markers appears multiple times on a wide map, 1920x1080 screen resolution, map height 500px and width 100% ([a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/f9jxtt34/1/)).

```
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 0,
            center: myLatlng
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

However, setting the markers as draggable makes the google maps api not to render the markers multiple times ([a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/wvch9qpu/1/)).

```
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 0,
            center: myLatlng
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**Question: How can I prevent marker duplicates while the markers remain undraggable?**

**Later Edit:** The map size cannot be changed.

Comment: You can change the Zoom level so you dont see the world map 3 times. Like here i updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9jxtt34/4/)

Comment: That is not an option. The maps must be 100% as width.

Comment: Zoom level 1 wont help you out also or? Because then you have the full world map. Not three times the same map.

Comment: Zoom level 1 still shows the markers three times. At zoom zero there are 3 maps: 1. left side of screen I have the right half of the map; 2. full width map; 3. right side of screen I have the left half of the map;

Comment: It shows it 3 times because you have a direct myLatlng point. First i let the draggable true under Marker then I tried `marker.setOptions({draggable: false});` or `marker.draggable(false)` but this did not do the trick. Probably by draggable true you dont have fix point and you can change it thats why it shows only one marker. I tried with the [event](http://jsfiddle.net/0mbrgyev/10/) but as soon as the mouse is over the marker, it shows again the other two. I think this looks like a dead end.

Comment: I already tried that before posting my question. It didn't work, because the moment the map sees `draggable: false` it's duplicating the markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help a bit, I set draggable to true but on the drag event set the position back to the original position.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 0,
    center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        crossOnDrag : false,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
var origPos = marker.getPosition();
marker.addListener("drag",function(e){marker.setPosition(origPos);})
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wvch9qpu/3/
the onlything still not right is the cursor changing to a pointer on hover, and the map not dragging when when you try to drag the marker, (you can spend some time fixing this by manually moving the map based on how much the user tried to drag the marker)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with two events as soon as you mouseout the other markers disappears.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
        marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
        marker.setMap(map);
        marker.setDraggable(true);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            marker.setDraggable(false);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
            marker.setDraggable(true);
        });
```

Here is the live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9mvz3gy8/1/)

Comment: The problem is that it's creating that annoying flickering effect.

Comment: Yes i know as soon as the the marker is draggable it creates the other markers, because it shows up the same place in 3 world maps. Actually it is right, because this is the point you wanna show on a map. So in this 3 same worlds, it has the exact same point. So this is usual that it will show you 3 markers. In draggable false you dont have any exact point. It is only a place holder marker. So you can change the location always.